# Cut away sides of image on small screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap and I have a banner (1920*250px) across the top of my page.
The banner is responsive (using `.img-responsive`).
On small screens (sm and xs) though I want to cut away the sides so that the banner has a new base width of 1140px (<del>I want to keep the base height at 250px</del> I want the image behave like it is 1140*250px and still be responsive), but I have no idea how to do that.
I'd be grateful for any help.

**Edit:** Here is a better explanation of what I want:
I have a banner that is 1920*250px big. It contains a section (1140*250px) in the center that contains a logo, I want this section always be entirely visible, the layout of the banner is roughly like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjLhj.jpg
The image is made responsive with `.img-responsive`, so that it resizes with the window. However, on small screens the center section with the logo is really small, so I want to get rid of the decorational side pieces. The remaining center section still needs to be responsive so that the logo remains fully visible.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9LdN.jpg

Comment: Could you provide more code, please!!

Comment: you should mark an answer as accepted if someone solved your problem!

Answer (score 0):

In a media query, you can absolutely position the image and use `left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%)` to center it horizontally while retaining the original height.

```css
.img-responsive { max-width: 100%; }

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  .cropped {
    position: relative;
    height: 250px;
  }
  .cropped .img-responsive {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    max-width: 150%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="cropped"><img src="http://placehold.it/1920x250" class="img-responsive"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but is it possible to do that with a dynamic height? I think my post was a bit confusing with saying "I want to keep the base height at 250px". I meant that I want the banner behave like a 1140*250px and still being responsive, sorry

Comment: @Niernen *"I want the image behave like it is 1140*250px and still be responsive"* can you explain that differently? If you want the sides cut off, at what point do you want the image to still be responsive? What's wrong with allowing the image to scale as it is nowIt sounds like what you want will distort the image. Maybe you can come up with a mockup of what you're trying to achieve so I can see it?

Comment: @Niernen if you want it to be responsive but cutting off *part* of the left/right edges, just change the `max-width` in the media query to something > 100%. I changed it to 150%, but the value you use there depends on your source graphic. We can't just guess at what parts of the image you want cut off - that's specific to your image. Try my updated code and tweak the `max-width` value in the media query and see if you can get it like you want it with your banner.

Answer (score 0):

If it can be absolutely positioned, you could use a css clip:

```
  img {
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(0px,1530px,250px,390px);
  }
```

Or (possibly a more sensible solution) you can put it in a parent container and hide overflow:

```
<div id="bannerContainer">
  <img src="blahblah.jpg" class="yourimage" alt="hi" />
</div>

#bannerContainer {
  width: 1140px;
  height: 250px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```