# Content below in flow of absolute banner image

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a banner picture that is supposed to display only for small devices a specified section. See also here: [Stackoverflow Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43742957/cut-away-sides-of-image-on-small-screens/43743422)

Unfortunately, this also means that the content below now overlaps and is no longer in the responsive flow with the height of banner image.

```
Here the Hello, I have a banner picture that is supposed to display only for small devices a specified section. See also here: [Stackoverflow Topic][1]
```

Unfortunately, this also means that the content below now overlaps and is no longer in the responsive flow with the height of banner image.

Here the [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/fekijujuli/1/edit?html,css,output)

```css
.img-responsive {
  max-width: 100%;
}
        
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  .cropped {
    position: relative;
    height: 250px;
  }

  .cropped .img-responsive {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    max-width: 150%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
   <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
   
</head>
<body>
   <section class="banner">
        <div class="cropped">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1601134728471-aa7f168d82ed?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1952&q=80" alt="" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
    </section>
    <nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
                <div class="navbar-nav">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-9 mx-lg-auto mt-5 mb-5">
                <h2 class="text-uppercase">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis, dolorum.
                </h2>

                <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed magni fugiat dolorum! Deserunt velit fuga provident, beatae delectus omnis culpa alias expedita, inventore molestiae aut explicabo? Nihil eum odit saepe voluptatem optio voluptatibus,
                    repudiandae laborum ducimus suscipit eius voluptatum porro debitis fugiat nobis ipsa inventore animi placeat expedita ex sint.</p>

                <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed magni fugiat dolorum! Deserunt velit fuga provident, beatae delectus omnis culpa alias expedita, inventore molestiae aut explicabo? Nihil eum odit saepe voluptatem optio voluptatibus,
                    repudiandae laborum ducimus suscipit eius voluptatum porro debitis fugiat nobis ipsa inventore animi placeat expedita ex sint.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Always a [mcve] in your question please. Not on a third party site. You saw the warning.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend removing the image from the HTML and instead applying it as a background image to the container in the CSS, like so:

```css
       .cropped {
            max-width: 100%;
            height: 250px;
            background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1601134728471-aa7f168d82ed?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1952&q=80);
            background-position: center; 
        }
        
        @media (max-width: 1000px) {
            .cropped {
                position: relative;
                height: 250px;
            }
            .cropped .img-responsive {
                position: absolute;
                left: 50%;
                transform: translateX(-50%);
                max-width: 150%;
            }
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
   <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
   
</head>
<body>

  
  
   <section class="banner">
        <div class="cropped">
            <img alt="" class="img-responsive">
        </div>

    </section>


    <nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
                <div class="navbar-nav">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-9 mx-lg-auto mt-5 mb-5">
                <h2 class="text-uppercase">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis, dolorum.
                </h2>

                <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed magni fugiat dolorum! Deserunt velit fuga provident, beatae delectus omnis culpa alias expedita, inventore molestiae aut explicabo? Nihil eum odit saepe voluptatem optio voluptatibus,
                    repudiandae laborum ducimus suscipit eius voluptatum porro debitis fugiat nobis ipsa inventore animi placeat expedita ex sint.</p>

                <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed magni fugiat dolorum! Deserunt velit fuga provident, beatae delectus omnis culpa alias expedita, inventore molestiae aut explicabo? Nihil eum odit saepe voluptatem optio voluptatibus,
                    repudiandae laborum ducimus suscipit eius voluptatum porro debitis fugiat nobis ipsa inventore animi placeat expedita ex sint.</p>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Note: I removed the image src from the html and applied the 'background-image' to the container that was holding the image.

you can also use values for the background image instead of 'center'. And there are different properties relating to the background image. See more here:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp